# Is it possible to get project metadata in cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I want to get project-wide metadata set in `compute engine` within my `GCP` cloud function. Is this possible?

Here is my try:

`metadata.js`:

```js
const request = require('request-promise');

async function getMetaData(attr) {
  const url = `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/attributes/${attr}`;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
    }
  };
  return request(url, options)
    .then(response => {
      console.info(`Retrieve meta data successfully. meta data: ${response.body}`);
      return response.body;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Retrieve meta data failed.', err);
    });
}

async function retrieveMetaData() {
  return {
    IT_EBOOKS_API: await getMetaData('IT_EBOOKS_API')
  };
}

module.exports = { getMetaData, retrieveMetaData };
```

cloud function `index.js`:

```js
const { retrieveMetaData } = require('./metadata');

async function retrieveComputeMetadata(req, res) {
  const envVars = await retrieveMetaData();
  console.log('envVars: ', envVars);
  res.status(200).json(envVars);
}

exports.retrieveComputeMetadata = retrieveComputeMetadata;
```

When I test the cloud function, the logs show me an error:

```
Retrieve meta data failed. { StatusCodeError: 404 - "404 page not found\n" at new StatusCodeError (/srv/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15) at ....
```

It seems the `url` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The API you're looking to hit '..v1/project/attributes/' isn't available. As Cloud Functions run on GAE Standard the there are details around which endpoints are [available here.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/accessing-instance-metadata#identifying_which_metadata_endpoint_to_use)